# Open Data for Economic and Business Research within Sport Management

Tags: analysis, programming

as a M.Sc. Sport Management, keen about dynamic documents for the purpose of  economic and business analytics with R, knitr, R markdown, and RStudio I am searching for open data in the area of sport, which could provide insight into new market trends and market demand in the broader field of sport. I am also interested into new ideas, how unsatisfied demand and gaps in the market can be identified using analytics of open data. Besides basic research, the insights are meant to serve as a foundation for the development of new, innovative products and services.

I am looking forward to your suggestions and ideas.

Yours,
Magnus

Answer (score 2):

[Here are the slides](http://slideshow-s9.github.io/open_data_world_cup.html#1) from the vienna.rb talk (I did not attend it) about Open Football(soccer) Data and the World Cup 2014. The presentation is really interesting and it gives a lot of ideas I think.

[Open Football on GitHub](https://github.com/openfootball) proposes a large collection of open football datasets.

[Here is a brilliant article called "ANALYZING A NHL PLAYOFF GAME WITH TWITTER"](http://www.danielforsyth.me/analyzing-a-nhl-playoff-game-with-twitter/). It's not really Open Data but it also gives ideas and some pieces of code !

[An interesting article](http://www.tableausoftware.com/public/blog/2014/03/what-should-football-clubs-do-data-2371) about data future in football (it's more economy than tech but I thought it's what you asked).

My selection is a little football-oriented, and I'm sure there are a lot of data in sports like baseball or NBA.

Hope it could help !

Comment: Thank you. 

Yes stuff like this is what I am searching for. In addition I would be also interested into data about active and passive sport consumers. Passive sport consumers could be stadium visitors and TV spectators, whereas active sport consumers could be participants at sporting events like marathons and other sporting festivals or individuals with specific sport identification like skiers, climbers, divers, surfers, etc. Mentioned that I predominantly in the economic and business oriented analysis of these target groups.

Many thanks in advance for further ideas and contributions.